# Webpack bundled aot-compiled src and raw src in one chunk. Is that correct?

Tags: javascript, angular, bundle, webpack-2, aot

i'm little bit confused how aot and webpack is working together without cli. It seems to me that my webpack-config bundled the aot precompiled src and the raw src in one chunk. I refer in particular to the angular-code itself. Please see my webpack-analyzer- screenshot. [image: webpack-analyzer-screenshot]

I thought actually the index.ngfactory.ts-part in compiled/@angular is the precompiled version of the @angular part in node_modules i'm using.
In my opinion the aot compilation of angular is the only one the browser needed for my dist-bundle. I don't know if that is the way aot is working, or do i have something else in my webpack-config (i.e. exclude raw-src, etc.  ?
I use the webpack-config from [here](https://github.com/qdouble/angular-webpack2-starter/blob/master/webpack.config.ts)